# Rename dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, object, dataframe

I have a list files that I want to iterate over and import as dataframes:

```
data_files = ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv']
```

I'm trying to iterate over the list and create eponymously name dataframes, kind of like doing the following manually:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')
data3 = pd.read_csv('data3.csv')
```

I tried this:

```
for i in data_files:
    name = i.split('.')
    name = pd.read_csv(name + ".csv")
```

The problem with the above is that it's just creating "i" as a dataframe, and not creating a set of eponymous dataframe objects. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why not just use a container?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I apologize, I'm relatively new to python.

Comment: Put them in something like a list, dictionary, tuple etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be overwriting your dataframe every time you iterate. Use a dictionary / list instead:

```
dataframes = dict()
for i in data_files:
    name = i.split('.')
    dataframes[name] = pd.read_csv(name + ".csv")
```

Afterwards, access your dataframe like `dataframes['data1']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary in which the data objects are stored:

```
data_dict = {}
for i in range(len(data_files)):
    data_dict[i] = pd.read_csv(data_files[i])
```

Also, calling `i.split('.')` creates a list of the form `['data1','csv']` which I am not sure if that is your intent when you then try and call `read_csv`, as you are functionally stating `read_csv(['data1', 'csv'] + '.csv')` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: oops, I meant i.split('.')[0]